# Not validating fields when one is not null - hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, validation

Do u have any ideas how to validate one object in this case? 
I have class A which is built of two another classes B and C:

```
public class A{
private B b;
private C c;
}
```

In that case I would like to validate all fields from object B, which looks like this:

```
public class B{
private String name;
private Long number;
}
```

This kind of object A is being passed into my Controller as request object, so that I'd like to validate it before it's sent. 
The point is that I'd like to validate ***name*** and ***number*** objects when they are both passed but if any of them is ***null*** then I'd just like to validate the one which is not ***null***.

Do you guys have any ideas how to do that? I made @Valid on A object as well as on B field but it shows no ConstraintValidatonException.

Problem solved - Validation doesn't work on Restcontroller method but after passing it on Service, everthing works well. I'm going to investigate it in a free time.

Comment: I believe it is only achievable by object level validation. So you would probably end up with `@Constraint(validatedBy = YourBValidator.class)` annotation on `class B`.

Answer (score 0):

I would leave a comment but I'm unable to so here is my answer:

Why dont you create a `validate` method in `class B` which you can call in `class A`.

Comment: Just because I would need to add like 15 other properties to Class B, so that I'd need to write huge validate method. I hope, there is a way in Hibernate Validation to do that.